# Check if SafeFileHandle has Data to read

Tags: c#, filestream

I'm working on a plug and play version POS for .NET Service Object. I have a FTDI device that has 2 devices on it. One is a MSR and the other is a RFID. For a quick catch up POS for .NET supports Plug in play if you give it a Hardware ID. The FTDI device's hardware id is `QUADPORT\QUAD_SERIAL_INTERFACE`. So on my Service Object (SO) I start it with this

```
[HardwareId("QUADPORT\\QUAD_SERIAL_INTERFACE")]
[ServiceObject(DeviceType.Msr, "FTDI Device", "MSR FTDI Device", 1, 8)]
public class FTDIDevice : Msr
{
...
}
```

In the open method I can query the DevicePath property and it is the correct DevicePath. As a quick test to make sure it was indeed talking to the serial port through the device path I opened a FileStream to this Device Path, then tried to open both of the Virtual Com Ports and sure enough one of them had "Access Denied". Awesome! My next test I did was to write to the RFID device since I know most all of the commands and how to format the byte array to communicate with the RFID device. In fact here is the code I use.

```
    public override void Open()
    {
        string str = this.DevicePath;
        handle_read = Kernel32.CreateExistingRWFile(str);
        FS_read = new FileStream(handle_read, FileAccess.ReadWrite, 9);

        Console.WriteLine("File Stream Created, Writing Open Sequence");
        byte[] open = { 0xAA, 0xBB, 0x04, 0xFB, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xF8 };
        FS_read.Write(open, 0, open.Length);

        //byte[] receive = new byte[11];
        //var something = FS_read.Read(receive, 0, receive.Length);
        //Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(receive, 0, something));
        //Close the FileStream and the SafeFileHandle
        close();
    }
    private SafeFileHandle handle_read;
    private FileStream FS_read;
```

The first time I ran this code I selected the MSR (there are 2 devices with the exact name both in device manager and in the microsoft test app, so I was guessing anyway) and sending that command gave me no response from the MSR (for obvious reasons, its not the RFID Device). According to the MSDN site the Read command blocks until at least one byte is read from my stream. That is a problem since the MSR does not respond to RFID commands. So essentially my program is deadlocked. I force closed the program then fired it up again and selected the RFID and the Read method did indeed return with a successful response from the RFID.

So my question is is how can I query the Stream to see if there was any response from my device? I've tried using the CanRead property (always returns true). I've tried using ReadByte to see if it would return -1 like the document said it is supposed to, but it too hangs. I tried using the Length property but it throws an exception saying that the Stream does not support seeking. It feels like I'm out of options, hence why I'm asking here. Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

Hans wants to see my how I created my handle

```
internal class Kernel32
{
    internal static SafeFileHandle CreateExistingRWFile(string devicePath)
    {
        return CreateFile(devicePath, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, IntPtr.Zero, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
    }

    internal const short FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL = 0x80;
    internal const short INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = -1;
    internal const uint GENERIC_READ = 0x80000000;
    internal const uint GENERIC_WRITE = 0x40000000;
    internal const uint FILE_SHARE_READ = 0x00000001;
    internal const uint FILE_SHARE_WRITE = 0x00000002;
    internal const uint CREATE_NEW = 1;
    internal const uint CREATE_ALWAYS = 2;
    internal const uint OPEN_EXISTING = 3;

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFile(string lpFileName, uint dwDesiredAccess, uint dwShareMode, IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes, uint dwCreationDisposition, uint dwFlagsAndAttributes, IntPtr hTemplateFile);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool ReadFile(SafeFileHandle hFile, byte[] lpBuffer, uint nNumberOfBytesToRead, ref uint lpNumberOfBytesRead, IntPtr lpOverlapped);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool WriteFile(SafeFileHandle hFile, byte[] lpBuffer, uint nNumberOfBytesToWrite, ref uint lpNumberOfBytesWritten, IntPtr lpOverlapped);
}
```

I was working with a BeginRead when I saw Hans suggest something, so far it EndRead always returns 0 :/

here is the code for that.

```
        byte[] receive = new byte[11];
        IAsyncResult iAR = FS_read.BeginRead(receive, 0, receive.Length, ASyncFileCallBack, receive);

        byte[] wildGuess = (byte[])iAR.AsyncState;
        Console.WriteLine("Guessing:{0}", BitConverter.ToString(wildGuess));
    }
    private void ASyncFileCallBack(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        byte[] buffer = (byte[])result.AsyncState;
        int length = FS_read.EndRead(result);

        if (length > 0)
            Console.WriteLine("Response:{0}", BitConverter.ToString(buffer, 0, length));
        else
            Console.WriteLine("No Resposne");
    }
```

The `guessing` always just spits out 11 0's almost immediatly. Shortly after "No Response" is put up on the Console.

Comment: FileStream.BeginRead().  Pretty unclear how you obtain the handle, it needs to be opened with FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED.

Comment: @HansPassant THank you for the OVERALAPPED trick. That helps me open the FileStream with the ASYNC = true. Now though if i call close on my handle it crashes with "Operation was cancelled" WinIO Error

Comment: That's normal, you cancelled it.  Use try/catch to catch expected exceptions.

Comment: interesting.. When I try this on another PC I get "No Response" back and close works just fine. The other pc is x86 win8 embedded and this pc is x64 win7 pro.. can that be related?

Comment: @HansPassant I didn't know it was expected. Is it safe to do that?

Comment: That's normal too, you didn't call BeginRead again so there was nothing cancelled.  Your callback should not run until there's *something* to read, why that doesn't work correctly is impossible to guess.  If the device name contains the word "COM" then use SerialPort instead.